# How to only make the middle flex component responsive?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent component who has three child components. The `display is set to flex` and `flex-direction to row`.

here is the code

JS part:

```
<div className='Container'>
    <div className='Text1'>26 Dec 22</div>
    <div className='Text2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div className='Text3'>128K</div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.Container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    gap:10px;
}

.Text1{
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.Text2{
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
}
.Text3{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is the image of the output:
[image]

When I change from desktop view to mobile view I want my result to be like this
[image]

As one can see only the middle component text was eliminated and `...` was added.

In my above code  when I change the view I get the result as

[image]

Please guide me on how to decrease the width of only the middle component and also add `...` when part of the middle component disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` CSS property and use it on the middle element.

> The text-overflow CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is signaled to users. It can be clipped, display an ellipsis ('…'), or display a custom string. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 10px;
}

.Text1 {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Text2 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* new line */
  overflow: hidden; /* new line */
  white-space: nowrap; /* new line */
}

.Text3 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Text1">26 Dec 22</div>
  <div class="Text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="Text3">128K</div>
</div>
```